# How can I get the mouse coordinates relative to a JFrame rather than the entire screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, mouselistener

**Question:**
I want to get the coordinates of my mouse relative to the JFrame instead of to the screen.  I am using a screen with an array of JPanels that change colour when I click on them.  How can I do this?

Most of the solutions I've been able to find suggest getting the coordinates of the component, but I can't do that as this would mean it would find the coordinates relative to each JPanel as well?

**Code:**

```
    public TestCoordinates() {
            initComponents();
            JPanel[][] arrGrid = new JPanel[3][4];
            int tileColour = 0;
    
            //nested for loops create the grid
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                tileColour++;
                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    arrGrid[y][x] = new JPanel();
                    add(arrGrid[y][x]);
                    arrGrid[y][x].setBounds((x * 100) + 100, (y * 100) + 100, 100, 100);
                    arrGrid[y][x].setVisible(true);
    
                    //sets grid colour to alternating colours
                    tileColour++;
                    double tileColourDouble = tileColour;
                    double tileColour2 = tileColourDouble / 2;
                    arrGrid[y][x].setBackground(Color.cyan);
                    if ((tileColour2 == Math.floor(tileColour2)) && !Double.isInfinite(tileColour2)) {
                        arrGrid[y][x].setBackground(Color.green);
                    } else {
                        arrGrid[y][x].setBackground(Color.cyan);
                    }
    
                    //adds mouse listener
                    arrGrid[y][x].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            int yCo = getRow(e.getLocationOnScreen().y - 100);
                            int xCo = getColumn(e.getLocationOnScreen().x - 100);
                            System.out.println(e.getLocationOnScreen());
                            System.out.println(yCo + ", " + xCo);
                            arrGrid[yCo][xCo].setBackground(Color.gray);
                        }
    
                        //converts screen location to single x-coordinate of clicked JPanel's y-coordinate
                        private int getRow(int y) {
                            int row = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < y / 100; i++) {
                                row++;
                            }
                            return row;
                        }
    
                        //converts screen location to single x-coordinate of clicked JPanel's x-coordinate
                        private int getColumn(int x) {
                            int column = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < x / 100; i++) {
                                column++;
                            }
                            return column;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not add a MouseListener to the frame as well? This listener would be solely for the purpose of getting the mouse information on the JFrame.

Comment: Something [like this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPoint(java.awt.Component,java.awt.Point,java.awt.Component)) might do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the coordinates of my mouse... I am using a screen with an array of JPanels that change colour when I click on them.

You don't need the mouse coordinates. You can just use the `getComponent()` method of the `MouseEvent` to get the component you clicked on. Then change the background.

```
arrGrid[y][x].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
```

Your current code is creating a unique listener for every component. This is unnecessary.

Instead create a generic listener that can be shared by all panels. So outside your looping code you would do something like:

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Component panel = e.getComponent();
        panel.setBackground( Color.GRAY );
    }
};
```

Then in your looping code you simply do:

```
arrGrid[y][x].addMouseListener( ml );
```

Comment: I still need the coordinates of the JPanel, because I'm reading them into a database. Is there any way to go about this?

Comment: @NiNoes Your welcome for the help. Your original question was about clicking on a panel and changing its color which has been solved. *I still need the coordinates of the JPanel* - still not understanding what you are asking. You have access to the location of the panel. So you can either use those values or if you are asking for the grid that was clicked, then you use the location divided by 100 like you currently do.